# Copado trying to click an element with ClickElement Xpath - QForce.Click Element' expected 1 to 4 non-named arguments, got 0

Tags: automation, ui-automation, browser-automation

In Copado Robotic testing,

Trying to click an element with the help of **ClickElement** keyword but it does not clicking any of the fields/element.

I followed as per the instruction mentioned in the [Copado official website](https://docs.copado.com/resources/Storage/copado-robotic-testing-publication/CRT%20Site/qwords-reference/current/qwords/_attachments/QMobile.html#Click%20Element), kindly advise on what I am missing here!

```
ClickElement         (//span[text()='Opportunities'])[1]    timeout=10
```

*Note: It works with ClickText very well, but I wanted to know about ClickElement*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Copado Robotic Testing - CRT needs an escape character before the **"="** sign.

```
ClickElement  (//span[text()\='Opportunities'])[1]  timeout=10
```

In Selenium/Cypress there is no need to do like this. Where as in CRT the xpath must be given in this way.